# android- custom spinner array adapter getDropDownView return null

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've a custom spinner adapter for my spinner . this is my adapter class:

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
// Initialise custom font, for example:
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "IRAN Sans Bold.ttf");
public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

// Affects default (closed) state of the spinner
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setTypeface(font);
    return view;
}

// Affects opened state of the spinner
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView view = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setTypeface(font);
    return view;
}
```

}

this is simple_spinner layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="16dip" />
```

the problem is, it makes the spinner and I can see the first array item in spinner but when I want to open the drop down spinner ,it return a null error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
                                                                                 at ir.babaarzooni.persiandesigners.MySpinnerAdapter.getDropDownView(MySpinnerAdapter.java:33)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:637)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:633)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.compatMeasureContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:560)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.access$500(AppCompatSpinner.java:64)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:751)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:776)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:434)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my array :

```
 <array name="NearAxL">
    <item>انتخاب AX</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>0.25</item>
    <item>0.5</item>
    <item>0.75</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>1.25</item>
    <item>1.5</item>
    <item>1.75</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>2.25</item>
    <item>2.5</item>
    <item>2.75</item>
    <item>3</item>
</array>
```

this is  java code:

```
     NearAxR.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter  (this,R.layout.simple_spinner,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NearAxL)));
```

what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Is it your font file is present in assets folder? As per your give path?

Comment: @RonakJoshi yes I've the font file

Comment: @jjones can you update your question with R.array.NearAxL contents.

Comment: I just tried your code without using your font style code. And its working. @jjones

Comment: @WaleedSarwar I update my question

Comment: @RonakJoshi I did it and still have the erorr

Comment: @jjones did you try my answer I think this would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<array name="NearAxL">
    <item>انتخاب AX</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>0.25</item>
    <item>0.5</item>
    <item>0.75</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>1.25</item>
    <item>1.5</item>
    <item>1.75</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>2.25</item>
    <item>2.5</item>
    <item>2.75</item>
    <item>3</item>
</array>
```

should be instead:

```
<string-array name="NearAxL">
    <item>انتخاب AX</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>0.25</item>
    <item>0.5</item>
    <item>0.75</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>1.25</item>
    <item>1.5</item>
    <item>1.75</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>2.25</item>
    <item>2.5</item>
    <item>2.75</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

The `array` element is for [Typed Arrays](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray). String arrays must use `string-array`.

if it's still not working try using the built-in spinner layout like below

```
NearAxR.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter  (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NearAxL)));
```